# Vectorized extracting a list from MATLAB Cell Array

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matlab-struct

I have a two-index MATLAB Cell Array (AllData{1:12,1:400}) where each element is a structure. I would like to extract a list of values from this structure.

For example, I would like to do something like this to obtain a list of 12 values from this structure

```
MaxList = AllData{1:12,1}.MaxVal;
```

This comes up with an error

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 12 results
```

I can do this as a loop, but would prefer to vectorize:

```
clear MaxList 
for i=1:12    
   MaxList(i) = AllData{i,1}.MaxVal; 
end
```

How do I vectorize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all structs are scalar and have the same fields, it's better to avoid the cell array and directly use a **struct array**. For example,

```
clear AllData
AllData(1,1).MaxVal = 10;
AllData(1,2).MaxVal = 11;
AllData(2,1).MaxVal = 12;
AllData(2,2).MaxVal = 13;
[AllData(:).OtherField] = deal('abc');
```

defines a 2×2 struct array. Then, what you want can be done simply as

```
result = [AllData(:,1).MaxVal];
```

---

If you really need a **cell array of scalar structs**, such as

```
clear AllData
AllData{1,1} = struct('MaxVal', 10, 'OtherField', 'abc');
AllData{1,2} = struct('MaxVal', 11, 'OtherField', 'abc');
AllData{2,1} = struct('MaxVal', 12, 'OtherField', 'abc');
AllData{2,2} = struct('MaxVal', 13, 'OtherField', 'abc');
```

you can use these two steps:

```
tmp = [AllData{:,1}];
result = [tmp.MaxVal];
```

Comment: Thanks so much - your two-step solution works perfectly to extract a list from this cell array!

Comment: Glad I could help. And welcome to the site! You may want to mark the question as accepted (left tick mark in the upper left) if it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer above as a starting point, it is also possible to extract a 2d array of vectors from the Cell Array Structure.   In each element of the 2d AllData cell array is a 2048 element vector called DataSet.  The following commands will extract all of these vectors to a 2d array:

```
tmp = [AllData{:,1}];
len = length(tmp(1).DataSet); % Gets the length of one vector of DataSet
tmp2 = [tmp.DataSet];  % Extracts all vectors to a large 1-d array
AllDataSets = reshape(tmp2,len,[])';  % Reshapes into a 2d array of vectors
```